# How to get focus from click event of a text to googleplaces autocomplete input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, focus, google-places-autocomplete

need your help for an app iam trying to develop. So I have used react native googleautoplaces complete for the location, which is shown in the first text input.

The page when loaded gets the current location based on geocoder, geolocation codes i have used.

What i need is that, when i click on the 'change' link, it should focus or select the location input.[page design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufcDB.jpg),[code for google autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HRwN.jpg),[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx2xh.jpg).

If i use ref, can i do like that. If yes, how to add multiple ref, because already another ref is used in the autocomplete.[ref method used inside autocomplete, which takes the address value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thZcW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete 
...
ref={(ref) => { this.ref_location = ref }

//your element where the "Change" is being pressed. I used a button just as an example

<Button
    title="Change"
    onPress={() => { this.ref_location.focus(); }}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, Iam new to react native , so can you explain how to do it. ? The ref inside the autocomplete is given like {this.ref = ref}

Comment: Can you provide some sample of your code and what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried it just the way you have told, and it worked. But i have a doubt, if we provide this autocomplete input i. Header component of Flatlist , Will it affect the on press working of the autocomplete.

Comment: //Autocomplete
<GooglePlacesAutoComplete 
               ref={ (ref) => { this.ref = ref;} }
            />

<View style={{width:'50%',marginTop:'4%'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.ref.focus()}}  style={{width:'50%',alignSelf:'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontFamily:'Poppins-Regular',fontSize:18,fontWeight:'300',color:'#444'}}>Change</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>

Comment: This is the code i have done, and it worked. But when the input gets focus and i type another location, the list shows the places, but click over the items is not registering...

Comment: I would either add an onPress event to the autocomplete input to .blur() the ref element or create a hook to listen if ref is focused and then .blur() it after with this.ref.blur()

Comment: What happens when we do like that and why do we have to that?